# EF Code First: Does not update foreign key constraint name when property is changed

Tags: entity-framework, migration

I probably found a bug... at least it's annoying to me so I would appreciate if someone confirms this:

```
public int PriorityConfigurationSettingId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PriorityConfigurationSettingId")]
public virtual PriorityConfigurationSetting
PriorityConfigurationSetting{get;set; }

to 

public int PriorityConfigurationSettingId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PriorityConfigurationSettingId")]
public virtual LookUp PriorityConfigurationSetting { get; set; }
```

When I change the name of a foreign key entity name from PriorityConfigurationSetting to LookUp. After done the model changes i try to get the script through EF Code Fist Migration, I didn't get any changes.

Comment: I edited a bit, could you check if this is ok ? But besides this, your question is unclear to me, could you  elaborate a bit (edit question).

Comment: I have updated the question